# How to get coordinates once you've navigated back from turning location on?

Tags: java, android

> Whats the best way to get the getCoordinates method to run, once you return from the intent that was used in order to turn the location on. When you backpress once you have turned the location on, what happens in the activity lifecylce and where would be the best place to then call the getCoordinates method once you have returned from turning the location on, or even to first check if the location is on and only if it is then run getCoordinates method?

**checkLocationOn**

```
public void checkLocationOn () {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false;

    try {
        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch(Exception ex) {}

    try {
        network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch(Exception ex) {}

    if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
        // notify user
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setTitle("Location Needed");
        dialog.setMessage("The devices location settings are not enabled, please enable it in order to use this application...");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Open Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(myIntent);

             }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

**getCoordinates**

```
 public void getCoordinates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                     lat = location.getLatitude();
                     lng = location.getLongitude();

                    latitude = Double.toString(lat);
                    longitude = Double.toString(lng);

                    SharedPreferences.Editor e = preferences.edit();
                    e.putString("myLats",latitude);
                    e.putString("myLngs",longitude);
                    e.commit();

                }
            });
}
```

**onCreateView**

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.job_search_fragment, container, false);

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());

        checkLocationOn();

        getCoordinates();

        //Please help here



    return v;
}
```

Comment: I think you shold follow this link=https://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `onResume` and call both `checkLocationOn();` and `getCoordinates();` from there.

If you are requesting continuous location updates, you can remove the request it in `onPause` method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks arsena, i just changed the checkLocationOn() to a boolean and then in the onResume() if the checkLocationOn() is true then i call the getCoordinate() like so.

```
public boolean checkLocationOn () {

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false;

    try {
        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch(Exception ex) {}

    try {
        network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch(Exception ex) {}
    if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
        // notify user
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setTitle("Location Needed");
        dialog.setMessage("The devices location settings are not enabled, please enable it in order to use this application...");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Open Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

then in onResume()

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(checkLocationOn()){
        getCoordinates();
    }
}
```

its working now